# Jenkins not able to locate remote Tomcat server

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, tomcat7, integration-testing

My integration tests are not able to start and stop a remote Tomcat server. Even though I am not using localhost, for some reason the tests try to start Tomcat server on the local machine. I am using tomcat7-maven-plugin in order to run start and stop tomcat located on remote machine.

## Jenkins Error Log:

```
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run-war (start-tomcat) < package @ cicd-demo <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run-war (start-tomcat) @ cicd-demo ---
[INFO] Running war on http://localhost:8080/cicd-demo
[INFO] Using existing Tomcat server configuration at C:\.jenkins\workspace\cicd-demo-it\target\tomcat
[INFO] create webapp with contextPath: /cicd-demo
[INFO] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
[ERROR] Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind <null>:8080
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:407)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:623)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.init(AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:981)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:814)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:341)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.run.AbstractRunMojo.startContainer(AbstractRunMojo.java:1238)
    at org.apache.tomcat.maven.plugin.tomcat7.run.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:592)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:347)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:154)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven31Launcher.main(Maven31Launcher.java:132)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main.launch(Maven31Main.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:136)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:71)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:121)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:49)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:325)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:106)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:376)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:190)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:181)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:49)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.bind(JIoEndpoint.java:394)
    ... 45 more
```

## pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.study</groupId>
    <artifactId>cicd-demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>${project.artifactId}</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <server.url>http://gsi-562826:8080/${project.artifactId}</server.url>
        <deploy.url>http://gsi-562826:8080/manager/text</deploy.url>
    </properties>

    <scm>
        <connection>scm:svn:https://gsi-547576/svn/jenkins-rnd/cicd-demo/trunk</connection>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://gsi-547576/svn/jenkins-rnd/cicd-demo/trunk</developerConnection>
        <url>https://gsi-547576/svn/jenkins-rnd/cicd-demo/trunk</url>
    </scm> 

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
            <version>2.15</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>     
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.44.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>true</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!--
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-deploy</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            -->

            <!-- Releasing a project -->
            <!--
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <tagBase>https://gsi-547576/svn/jenkins-rnd/${project.artifactId}/tags</tagBase>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            -->

            <!-- Embedded integration testing with localhost Tomcat -->
            <!-- IT can be run using "mvn verify" -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>${deploy.url}</url>
                    <server>tc-servers</server>
                    <path>/${project.artifactId}</path>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>start-tomcat</id>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run-war</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <fork>true</fork>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop-tomcat</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shutdown</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- Integration tests -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- Can be executed using "mvn tomcat7:redeploy -Ptst" -->
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>tst</id>
            <properties>
                <server.url>http://gsi-547576:8080/${project.artifactId}</server.url>
                <deploy.url>http://gsi-547576:8080/manager/text</deploy.url>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <server.url>http://aws-ec2-server:8080/${project.artifactId}</server.url>
                <deploy.url>http://aws-ec2-server:8080/manager/text</deploy.url>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your tomcat already up and running? Jenkins seem to complain that it is unable to start tomcat as the port 8080 is already in use.

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind <null>:8080
```

Try running `shutdown.bat/shutdown.sh` script of tomcat to shutdown server and try again from Jenkins.

Comment: Since I have deployed Jenkins war on my localhost Tomcat it will remain up and running. But what I am trying to do here is start and stop remote Tomcat server located on `gsi-562826` machine.

Comment: Double check if you are really stopping and starting the server... apparently the stop part seems missed as starting is giving a bind exception.

Comment: I rebooted my remote machine and ran the build job again but no luck :( Also tried hitting `http://localhost:8080` in the browser and nothing showed up which confirmed that Tomcat is not running on remote machine. Now, looking at the logs shows that Jenkins is trying to start `localhost:8080` Tomcat server instead of `gsi-562826:8080` which is puzzling me.

Comment: No, because the `tomcat7-maven-plugin` is supposed to start the tomcat server, run integration tests and then stop it.